# Can I make a daily local notification with a variable message from the server in an android phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins, local

I'm building an android app using Phonegap 2.9.0. I want to make a daily local notification that shows a variable message from the server. I used this plugin:
https://github.com/zhuochun/local-notification

The plugin helps to make the daily local notification but with a static message. What I want to do is when the local notification is about to show, it connects to the server first to get the message of this day then shows the message from the server.

I'm trying to find out a way to do that because I do not want to make a server-side implementation for the normal push notifications.

Is there a way to do that?

The JS code to add notification:

notification.add({
                id : id,
                date : new Date(),
                message : "Phonegap - Local Notification",
                subtitle: "Subtitle is here",
                ticker : "This is a sample ticker text",
                repeatDaily : true
              });

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can use variable name instead of string to show dynamic notification,to get notification from server you can use call ajax to get latest notification ,before calling local notification.